# What magic does staticmethod() do, so that the static method is always called without the instance parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-methods

I am trying to understand how static methods work internally. I know how to use `@staticmethod` decorator but I will be avoiding its use in this post in order to dive deeper into how static methods work and ask my questions.

From what I know about Python, if there is a class `A`, then calling `A.foo()` calls `foo()` with no arguments whereas calling `A().foo()` calls `foo()` with one argument where that one argument is the instance `A()` itself.

However, in case of static methods, it seems always `foo()` is called with no arguments whether we call it as `A.foo()` or `A().foo()`.

Proof below:

```
>>> class A:
...     x = 'hi'
...     def foo():
...         print('hello, world')
...     bar = staticmethod(foo)
...
>>> A.bar()
hello, world
>>> A().bar()
hello, world
>>> A.bar
<function A.foo at 0x00000000005927B8>
>>> A().bar
<function A.foo at 0x00000000005927B8>
>>> A.bar(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
>>> A().bar(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

So am I right in concluding that the `staticmethod()` function does some magic such that `foo()` is always called with 0 arguments?

If I were to define my own `staticmethod()` in my own Python code, how would I do it? Is it even possible to define such a method from our own Python code, or can such a function be only defined as a builtin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's implemented as a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#definition-and-introduction). For example:

```
In [1]: class MyStaticMethod(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self, func):
   ...:         self._func = func
   ...:     def __get__(self, inst, cls):
   ...:         return self._func
   ...:     

In [2]: class A(object):
   ...:     @MyStaticMethod
   ...:     def foo():
   ...:         print('Hello, World!')
   ...:         

In [3]: A.foo()
Hello, World!

In [4]: A().foo()
Hello, World!
```

In the same way you can define `classmethod`, just passing the `cls` to the original function:

```
In [5]: from functools import partial
   ...: 
   ...: class MyClassMethod(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self, func):
   ...:         self._func = func
   ...:     def __get__(self, inst, cls):
   ...:         return partial(self._func, cls)

In [6]: class A(object):
   ...:     @MyClassMethod
   ...:     def foo(cls):
   ...:         print('In class: {}'.format(cls))
   ...:         

In [7]: A.foo()
In class: <class '__main__.A'>

In [8]: A().foo()
In class: <class '__main__.A'>
```

Comment: Instead of `partial(self._func, cls)`, [`classmethod.__get__`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/62cf4e77f785/Objects/funcobject.c#l750) basically uses `types.MethodType(self._func, cls)`.

Answer (score 5):

Methods, including instance, static, and class methods, work through the [descriptor protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html). If an object in a class dict implements the `__get__` special method:

```
class Descriptor(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, klass):
        return instance, klass

class HasDescriptor(object):
    descriptor = Descriptor()

x = HasDescriptor()
```

then the following attribute accesses:

```
x.descriptor
HasDescriptor.descriptor
```

will call the descriptor's `__get__` method to compute their value, like so:

```
descriptor.__get__(x, HasDescriptor)
descriptor.__get__(None, HasDescriptor)
```

Functions, `staticmethod`, and `classmethod` all implement `__get__` to make method access work. You can do the same:

```
class MyStaticMethod(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def __get__(self, instance, klass):
        return self.f
```

There are also `__set__` and `__delete__` methods that allow you to control setting and deleting attributes, respectively. Methods don't use these, but `property` does.